# Add WordPress visual editor in HTML textarea

Tags: wordpress

I created an HTML text area in frontend. Now, how to add WordPress visual editor in the HTML text area?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) as it's rich text editor. There are a variety of plugins you can use to make it available on the front end, and there is information about working with TinyMCE in the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE).

A word of warning about allowing your users to create HTML from the front end that you might serve back on your site. It is a really open vector for scripting attacks, especially if the form is more-or-less open to the public. You might want to look at a Markdown editor instead, if it still meets with your specifications.